# Chrome debugger doesn't show Fetch requests in Networks

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I have a `Fetch API` in my `ReactJS` Application in `Dashboard.jsx` component.  I am successfully getting the data using `fetch api` but the request to URL `fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/test")` not showing in `google chrome debugger`.

Its not in `All` tab

[image]

Its also not in 'Fetch/XHR'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have entered "r" into the filter text field, so you only see requests that matches the filter.